# Snack bar not displayed

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I'm inheriting from `BaseActivity` for all the other activities.

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id
                .coordinatorLayout1);
    }
}
```

activity_base.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.Activity.BaseActivity"> 
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Snackbar is not displayed when tried to access from a non-activity class.

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(
        BaseActivity.coordinatorLayout,
        "Helooo....",
        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
);
```

Comment: inside `build.gradle` do you have `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'`

Comment: try Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                            .make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout1), "Helooo....", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackbar.show();

Comment: "com.android.support:design:22.2.0" this was already there in the build.gradle.

Comment: @Shishram, findViewById cannot be called from non activity class

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Make a `public` method in a `Util class` and dont make the `cordinatorLayout` as `public static`. Keep the `weakReference` of your `Activity's` instance and through that you can show the `SnackBar`.
Method given below.

```
public void showSnackBar(Activity activity, String message){
    View rootView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    Snackbar.make(rootView, message, duration).show();
}
```

Comment: I've passed the app context to the showSnackBar(), View rootView = ((Activity) context).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewByIdfindViewById(android.R.id.content);,            no error but it doesn't execute Snackbar.make(rootView, text, duration).show();

Comment: Pass the activity instance

Comment: Thanks @zeus, I've passed the current activity's instance and it worked.

Comment: Feeling grt it helped :)

Comment: I'm using getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView() and it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you passing Activity or Context?

Comment: I tried this approach but it did not work. I just copied and pasted this in my fragment class. The method is called and exectued but I don't see any Snackbar (and no error message). So I have 3 questions. 1) What is Util class? 2) Do I have to specify the Snackbar in the XML (I use a one activity and multiple fragments layout) 3) What is android.R.id.content?

Answer (score 2):

```
private static final String message = "No Internet Connection";

public  static void message(Activity activity) {
    View rootView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    Snackbar.make(rootView, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```