# How to show SnackBar in BottomSheetDialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottom-sheet, android-snackbar

I search alot but couldn't find any solution[image: Can I display material design Snackbar in dialog?] and [Snackbar is not working within fragment class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305627/snackbar-is-not-working-within-fragment-class) doesn't help. I pass rootView of fragment and also try passing a view from getActivity but none of them works!

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_dialog_bottom_sheet, container, false);

Snackbar.make(MyActivity.myTextview, "Hello", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();

Snackbar.make(rootView, "Hello", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();

return rootView;

}
```

and my content_dialog_bottom_sheet :

```
 <RelativeLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/bottomSheetLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@color/background"
   app:behavior_hideable="true"
   app:behavior_peekHeight="180dp"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

  //some views 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add some code please

Comment: @ImAtWar I added

Comment: Show your layout file code please.

Comment: If it is still actual [https://stackoverflow.com/a/34477987/4486007](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34477987/4486007)
helped.

Answer (score 51):

Solution is fairly simple. You need to:

1. Wrap your dialog layout with `CoordinatorLayout` (and if you want to show snackbar just next to some specific view, wrap it instead)
2. Use `CoordinatorLayout` id as view while showing snackbar.

Comment: Thank you. :). This work after spending 2 hours to the gutter. :)

Answer (score 23):

```
Snackbar.make(
            getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView(),
            "your-string",
            Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
    ).show();
```

Add this peace of code to your **onCreateView**

Comment: If a keyboard is available, the snack bar will be hidden behind it

Answer (score 2):

Show snackbar after a delay:

```
   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
        public void run() {
            Snackbar.make(rootView, "Hello", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();

        }
    },200);
```

Comment: if you want to show snackbar in oncreateview. Do that with postdelay. Otherwise on button click can can show that direact it works.

Comment: Its a simple click listener!

Answer (score 2):

If you are extending your Bottomsheet class to BottomSheetDialogFragment(), you can use dialog's decorView as a view.

Sample Code Snippet for reference :

```
Snackbar.make(
                            dialog?.window?.decorView,
                            "Press login button to continue",
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
                        )
                            .setAction("Login") { v: View? ->
                                val intent = Intent(context, DestinationActivityAfterLogin::class.java)
                                startActivity(intent)
                            }.show()
```

====

If you are using BottomSheetDialog for showing the bottomsheet, there one can use rootView to pop-up snackbar.

Sample code for reference :

```
Snackbar.make(
                bsBinding.root.rootView, // bsBinding is view binding object
                "Press login button to continue",
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
                        )
                            .setAction("Login") { v: View? ->
                                val intent = Intent(context, DestinationActivityAfterLogin::class.java)
                                startActivity(intent)
                            }.show()
```

Hope this would be useful while showing snackbar with bottom sheet dialogs.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

using [@Wimukthi Rajapaksha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10505343/wimukthi-rajapaksha) answer:

```
Snackbar.make(
        getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView(),
        "your-string",
        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
).show();
```

you can use the following code line to show it above a certain view, make sure to show the snack bar after setting anchor view not before.

`snackBar.anchorView = -Your view-`